# Is there a way to have floating areas so we can work on more than 1 screen on Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, workflow, desktop-application

I am currently setting up my new desktop, and I am trying to optimise my workflow on Xcode. I am working on 2 screens, and I am trying to separate the different areas on Xcode.

Xcode currently have 4 areas :

- The Navigator Area
- The Editor Area
- The Debug Area
- The Utilities Area

[image: Screenshots]

Right now, they are all setup on 1 window, and there is not a single option to separate them. 
The only way to separate them is to open a new editor for one file, but then when I'll want to change the focus file, it won't change in the new window, but in the main window with the different areas.

Is there a way to put the Navigator, Debug and Utilities Areas on my second screen and have my editor area on my main screen ? 
If not, how do you improve the workflow and increase the size of your editor ? It's pretty small when all areas are open.

Comment: `CDM + option + Enter` for open another screen on XCode, for close this screen `CMD + Enter`

Answer (score 1):

I believe Xcode has not reached to a level where it can suffice your expectations but yes in order to focus particularly on your editor section what best you can do is 
From top right corner (3 blue window style buttons) you can disable your

- navigator section
- Debug area
- utilities section

You can code then in your editor and whenever whichever component you require you can enable from the same place.

I can also suggest you something extra i.e. when you are editing in multiple files you can open the files in tab format (just right click on the file and select open in new tab)